# The question could be merged several times if you resend merge request

Tags: bug, status-deferred, moderator-tools, timeline, merged-questions

1. Merge a question.
2. Press F5 (try to refresh the page) on the redirected page (where you look on the merge result).
3. The browser will ask you, if you want to resend post request.
4. Chose resend.
5. New record about the merge will be created in the question timeline.

For example, [timeline of this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1108133/timeline).

> [image: 2 records about the merge in the question timeline]

Comment: It falls under "Just don't do it" category, IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou it should be validated on the server side)

Comment: Agreed. It *sounds* like a security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This is on our list to address and will update here once we get to it.